# Output formatted XML to Console / Debug with custom indent length

Tags: xml, vb.net, winforms

I am looking for a method to write formatted XML to the console or debug output window, with a customized indent length. The default XML Document indent value seems to be 2 spaces. I wish to change the indent from two spaces `("  ")` to four `("    ")`.

From:

```xml
<urlset>
  <url>
    <loc>/js/lazyload.js</loc>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

To:

```xml
<urlset>
    <url>
      <loc>/js/lazyload.js</loc>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

I am using: `XmlDocument` and `OuterXml` to get the contents of the XML Document to a string. I then parse the string and print it to the output window using: `Debug.WriteLine(XElement.Parse(XMLDoc.OuterXml).ToString())`.

My Code:

```vb
' Create XML Document
Dim XMLDoc As New XmlDocument
With XMLDoc

    ' Add Urlset
    Dim XMLSchema As XmlElement = .CreateElement("urlset")
    .AppendChild(XMLSchema)

    ' Add URLs
    For Each Script In ScriptsList
        Dim XMLUrl As XmlElement = .CreateElement("url")
        XMLSchema.AppendChild(XMLUrl)

        Dim XMLLoc As XmlElement = .CreateElement("loc")
        XMLLoc.InnerText = Script
        XMLUrl.AppendChild(XMLLoc)
    Next

    ' Write To Output Window
    Debug.WriteLine(XElement.Parse(XMLDoc.OuterXml).ToString())

End With
```

I have two questions regarding parsing and indenting lines.

1. I am currently using `XElement` to parse the document, which is a part of the LINQ library. Is there another way to parse the document that is using the standard XML library `Imports System.Xml`? *Note: I do understand that LINQ is also a part of that library.* (`Imports System.Xml.Linq`)
2. I read that I can use `XmlWriterSettings` to change the indent and indent characters. However it seems like I would have to manually output each line manually: [Link to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings?view=netframework-4.8). I am looking for a method that allows me to only provide a string that will then automatically be formatted and outputted to the output log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a  [System.Xml.XmlWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter) class, it allows to output the XmlDocument content to a `StringBuilder` object, which can be specified in the [XmlWriter.Create()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.create) method.

The [XmlWriterSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings) class allows to specify whether indentation is used, which character generates the indentation and the width of the indentation (how many chars will compose the indentation).

After you created the `XmlDocument`, add:
(`ChrW(32)` is the space char. You can use any other. E.g., a dot: `"."c`)

```
Dim indentWidth As Integer = 4
Dim XMLDoc As New XmlDocument
With XMLDoc 
    (...)
End With

Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
Dim settings = New XmlWriterSettings() With {
        .Indent = True,
        .IndentChars = New String(ChrW(32), indentWidth),
        .CloseOutput = True
    }

Dim writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings)
XMLDoc.WriteTo(writer)
writer.Dispose()
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
```

Comment: This solves my problem! Funnily enough, I just solved it myself using the exact same method as yours, just a minute before you posted it.